# Point data request from WMS, WFS, WCS using lat lon or station ID

Tags: wms, wfs, wcs

What is the best service to use when requesting data for a specific point?  For example we have graphical data that we can expose using any of the services.  If we want to build a request url that uses a lat/lon point or even an airport ID, which service would be optimal?  We want to provide known points within the request.

Comment: All allow requests by lat lon.

Comment: @nmtoken can you provide a dummy url request that uses lat lon in WMS?

Comment: it's done using the BBOX parameter, where the CRS is specified in degrees like EPSG:4326 like: http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/UGA_ARGI/ows?language=eng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=2.709326463518560768,32.05121695945936722,2.70932827140950705,32.05121993538037373&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=200&HEIGHT=200&LAYERS=BEDROCK_AGE&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE

Comment: And info on a feature at a pixel location would be: http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/UGA_ARGI/ows?language=eng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&BBOX=2.709326463518560768,32.05121695945936722,2.70932827140950705,32.05121993538037373&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=200&HEIGHT=200&LAYERS=BEDROCK_AGE&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&j=0&i=200&QUERY_LAYERS=BEDROCK_AGE&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If query by airport ID is a requirement then WFS is the only solution. WMS and WCS does not support queries by attributes. WMS GetFeatureInfo supports only query by a point and even then some tweaking would be needed for making it to work with lat/lon coordinates. WCS is all wrong service for your needs because it can only deliver coverages (usually raster data) but not information about features.

I would go with WFS with PropertyIsEqualTo of PropertyIsLike filters for attributes and DWithin filter for searching features nearby.